# open Onboard when using touch screen

Tags: touchscreen, onboard

**Hey guys, my English is not good. sorry :(**

My laptop have touchScreen and my version of linux is Xubuntu 16.04
i want xubuntu show "Onboard" when i clicking on text box with touchScreen.(like how its work on windows 10, that show onboard just when touch text box with touchScreen)
it this possible?
and one more question. my screen have 360 degree hinge, its rotate in windows  when i spin laptop, and not rotating in Ubuntu,Xubuntu or kali... can tell me a solution for this ?

Comment: open `onboard settings` and check `autoshow when editing text` box